# Android change Fragment when close ActivityDialog

Tags: android, android-activity, view, fragment

I want to change Fragment when I close the activity. I tried to enter into the activity, the FragmentTransaction but it is not the correct way. How can I do? Thank you

```
Fragment newFragment = new Ele_Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a tag to the addToBackStack instead of passing null

```
.addToBackStack(Ele_Fragment.TAG);
```

this way you have a hook into the fragments you are passing.